# How to save and reload a JTree when running a program subsequent times?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

We have written code for a `JTree` where we can add and remove nodes dynamically.

However, we cannot save the tree. Each time we run the program, we cannot get the previously created tree.

How can the `JTree` be saved and loaded?

Answer (score 2):

You can [Serialize/Deserialize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/) your JTree, this is an example :

```
   JTree tree=new JTree();

   ....

   //serialization
    try{
        FileOutputStream file= new FileOutputStream("/home/alain/Bureau/serialisation.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
        out.writeObject(tree);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    //Deserialization
    JTree tree2=null;
    try{
        FileInputStream file= new FileInputStream("/home/alain/Bureau/serialisation.txt");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file);
        tree2 = (JTree) in.readObject();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
```

Note that [`transient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3) fields are not Serializable so **you should also serialize your TreeModel**.